# finding odds and evens of user idea

Tags: python

i want to make program that it get a list of numbers from user and then find even numbers and odd numbers and print it.here is my code.please help me.i want my output should be list.this code has error now!!!

```
def find_evens_and_odds()
    numbers=list(input("give me your list:"))
    
    evens=list()
    
    odds=list()
        
             
    for i in numbers:
        if i % 2 ==0:
            evens.append(i)
                
        else:
            odds.append(i)  
            
    print(numbers)
    
    print(evens,odds)
```

Comment: what is the error? there isn't anything preventing the user from inputting a list in any format they choose, the numbers will be strings, not integers, and your function doesn't handle any of this

Comment: What is the error. Edit your question to include full error message and expected output.

Comment: `input` returns a string. `list`, when applied on a string, returns a list of strings (characters). You can't `% 2` a string. You need to convert numbers from input to integers

Comment: Did you try to print `numbers` after you defined it? Does it contain what you think?

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
 how can i fix that? if my input be list it will not work(i mean if i give it a list i face with this error).

Comment: can you correct  my error and send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ast

def find_evens_and_odds():

    number=input("give me your list ") # Enter like this [1,2,3]
    numbers= ast.literal_eval(number)
    evens=[]
    odds=[]        
    for i in numbers:
        if int(i) % 2 ==0:
            evens.append(i)      
        else:
            odds.append(i)  
            
    print(numbers)
    print(evens,odds)

find_evens_and_odds()
```

Comment: if i give him this>>>>[1,2,3,4,5,6]   the error will be: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1'

Comment: for above code you can give like this     1,2,3,4

Comment: i  know thank you very much for you're help but what if i give [1,2,3,4,5,6]? then what should i do?

Comment: @Parsasoleymani You should use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert that to a list of numbers.

Comment: @Barmar where should i add it? i tried but couldn't reach my goal. i want to give to this program a list.

Comment: After you get the input, use `numbers = ast.literal_eval(numbers)`

Comment: @Barmar it works.thank you.sorry i ask you and for output if i want to print in form of tuple,do you know what should i add?

Comment: i did this >>>> result=tuple(evens,odds)
    print(result)   
but the error was::TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2

Comment: `result = (evens, odds)` @Parsasoleymani

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_evens_and_odds(numbers):
    evens = list()
    odds = list()
    for i in numbers:
        if i % 2 == 0: 
            evens.append(i)
        else:
            odds.append(i)
            
    print(numbers)
    print(evens, odds)
    
numbers = list(map(int,input().split()))
find_evens_and_odds(numbers)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.